# What's a single word to name a person/entity that determines?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, agent-nouns

I am looking for a single word (noun) describing a person or any other entity that *determines* something. For example:

> John determines next year goals for his employees. John is a ... of employee next year goals.

I was thinking about **determiner** but that somehow does not sound well...

Comment: *Next year goals* is an awkward noun phrase.  *Employee next year goals* is more so.

Comment: Agreed, it's better to rephrase it to something like "John is a ... of his employees' goals for the next year"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not sound well for you because this word is widely used as a grammar term. However, if we look the word up in the [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/determiner), we see:

> "a person or thing that determines or decides something"

Therefore this word is suitable in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The question may be a tad too general--much depends on the nature of the thing determined (is it as big and real as a war, or as small and abstract as a commercial slogan?) as well as the circumstances/bailiwick of the decision-making, especially the question of how weakly or strongly the outcome is contested. Depending on this plethora of factors, the person could be **author** (as in your example), **judge, lynch-pin, final authority, powerhouse, trend-setter, juggernaut, mandarin, bulldozer, leader, boss, bigshot, arbiter,** etc.

"Many people pushed World War II to its conclusion, from Rosie the Riveter to Adolf Hitler, but ultimately it was Winston Churchill who was the **pivot** on which it turned."